# How to avoid audio border magnetics on Final Cut Pro X?

Tags: audio, final-cut-pro-x

This might be an easy question, but I'm not able to find the answer.
Sometimes the audio clip is slightly small than the video clip. I need to move the audio just a little bit (like less than 1 second), however final cut moves it to the opposite border straight away.

Comment: Is `Snapping` (`N`) off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `Snapping` is turn on. Toggle it with `N` or use the snapping icon (next to clip view options and transitions etc).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Zoom in for more precise placements and turn snapping off.